# Unexpected different status code from apache for different browsers

Tags: php, http, apache2

I´m working on a theme for a shop system at the moment and I found a wery strange bug.

When **submitting a form (POST)** I get the following result:

- Chrome: 302 Status + new Location in response header (CORRECT)
- Firefox: 200 Status + now Location in response header (INCORRECT)

I´ve **compared the posted data** and **all headers** and they are all equal besides these  differences:

- Request-Header: different User-Agent (no surprise)
- Response-Header:
  Firefox: Content-Type: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", in Chrome:
  Content-Type: "text/plain;"

It could not be a apache-only problem, cause when I´m using the original theme, I get the expected 302 status code also on Firefox.

I´m running out of ideas already - maybe someone has a hint for me?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Michael

Comment: You should create simple PHP form (without your shop system) to make sure it works fine in both browsers at the beginning.

Comment: When you say 'now' vs 'new', is that just a typo? And when you say FALSE vs CORRECT, do you mean INCORRECT vs CORRECT ?

Comment: PHP Form works - also do other themes. I´ve changed the text as suggested.